# Old datastax enterprise tarball downloads?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have an old datastax cluster running 4.5.1, wanted to see if I could upgrade it.  Based on the datastax documentation, it "looks" like there is an interim upgrade requirement to 4.8 before jumping to 5.1, can anyone confirm this?  And if so, is there a Datastax download archive anywhere?

The oldest version I can download from Datastax's site is 5.1, so I guess the older versions aren't available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no visual way to get a previous release via [Download section of the DataStax's site](https://downloads.datastax.com/#ddac). But all files are still available there if you use the URL of following form:

```
http://downloads.datastax.com/enterprise/dse-${version}-bin.tar.gz
```

where `${version}` is specific version of DSE. URLs were in the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/install/installDsePrevious.html).

To upgrade you'll need to go following way: 4.5.1 -> 4.5.9 (latest of 4.5.x) -> 4.8.16 -> 5.0.15, and from that you can just follow existing upgrade guide to go to 5.1.x (latest right now is 5.1.16), or to 6.0.x/6.7.x.  Please follow on steps in the [upgrade documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgrdDSE.html).